# R, ClickHouse: Expected: FixedString(34). Got: UInt64: While processing

Tags: r, dbi, clickhouse

I am trying to query data from ClickHouse database from R with subset.
Here is the example

```
library(data.table)
library(RClickhouse)
library(DBI)

subset <- paste(traffic[,unique(IDs)][1:30], collapse = ',')

conClickHouse <- DBI::dbConnect('here is the connection')


DataX <- dbgetdbGetQuery(conClickHouse, paste0("select * from database
                    and  IDs in (", subset ,") ", sep = "") )
```

As a result I get error:

> DB::Exception: Type mismatch in IN or VALUES section. Expected: FixedString(34).
> Got: UInt64: While processing (IDs IN ....

Any help is appreciated

Thanks to the comment of @DennyCrane,

```
"select * from database where toFixedString(IDs,34) in
     (toFixedString(ID1, 34), toFixedString(ID2,34 ))"
```

This query subset properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/#strong-typing

Strong Typing

In contrast to standard SQL, ClickHouse has strong typing. In other words, it doesn’t make implicit conversions between types. Each function works for a specific set of types. This means that sometimes you need to use type conversion functions.

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#tofixedstrings-n

```
select * from (select 'x' B ) where B in (select toFixedString('x',1))
DB::Exception: Types of column 1 in section IN don't match: String on the left, FixedString(1) on the right.
```

use casting toString or toFixedString

select * from (select 'x' B ) where **toFixedString**(B,1) in (select toFixedString('x',1))